# What can gems be spent on?

Tags: clash-royale

I have started playing clash royale and have gotten a few gems. What can gems be spent on other than opening chests immediately?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Gems can be used to open chests or buy gold.

Comment: You can buy chests with them (and they are opened immediatly), or open them.

Comment: No problem, makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 7):

Gems can be spent on a few different things:

- **To unlock chests:**
  [image: Picture of chest unlock]
- **As a substitute for gold anywhere gold is used:**
  [image: Picture of gold substitute screen]
  <sup>This works nicely if you are missing a bit for an epic.</sup>
- **To purchase chests:**
  [image: Purchase chests purchase screen]
- **And to purchase gold directly:**
  [image: Picture of gold purchase screen]

Comment: How did you've got a Super Magical Chest, anyway?

Comment: @John It's random.

Comment: I know, but it's extremely rare. @Michael

Answer (score 4):

Well that's the main thing to spend them on - opening chests.
Other than that you can go to the first tab "Shop" and buy **Chests** or **Gold**.
But my recommendation is save up and only speed up chests when you need to, as buying chests is not really worth it. Maybe an occasional 1000G from gems to buy an epic (that costs 2000G) would be worth it though.

Comment: I don't think that this is a duplicate, considering the other question is entirely opinion based and that is frowned upon on this website.